# Iam unable to fecth records data into LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

HTML:

```html
<template>
    <h1>Blood Donors Details</h1>
    <div if:true={record}>
        <lightning-datatable data={record} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
    <div if:true={error}>{error}</div>

</template>
```

JS:

```js
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import allrecord from '@salesforce/apex/GetRecordBldDonor.displayRecords';

export default class Getrecord extends LightningElement {

columns=[{label:'Name',fieldname:'Name',type:'text',sortable:true},
{label:'BloodGroup',fieldname:'Blood_Group__c',type:'text',sortable:true},
{label:'Age',fieldname:'Age__c',type:'number',sortable:true},
{label:'State',fieldname:'State__c',type:'text',sortable:true},
];

record='';
error='';
@wire(allrecord)
allrecord({data,error})
{
    if(data){
        this.record=data;
       console.log(this.record);        
    }
    else if(error)
    {
        this.error=error;
    }
}

}
```

Apex:

```java
public with sharing class GetRecordBldDonor {
   @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Blood_Donor__c> displayRecords(){  
    try {
        System.debug('records'+[select Name,
        Blood_Group__c,
        Age__c,
        State__c from Blood_Donor__c]);

        return([select Name,
        Blood_Group__c,
        Age__c,
        State__c from Blood_Donor__c]);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fieldname` should be `fieldName`. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so you must make sure you read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Tq My problem got solved